# Find the path to parent node in a tree from a given node

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given a `tree` describe below, given an `node` say `9` print the path from give node to `root` node.

```
let sampleData = {
id: 1,
children: [{
    id: 2,
    children: [{
        id: 5,
        children: [{
            id: 8
        }]
    },
        {
            id: 6
        }
    ]
},
    {
        id: 3,
        children: [{
            id: 9
        }, {id: 10 }]}, {
        id: 4
     }
     ]
  }
```

for example if 9 is given output should be then output should be `1 , 3, 9`

Comment: We can transform this input using DFS and backtrack once we find the id we looking for. 
Keep doing dfs and note the backtrack when reached ID

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. There are hundreds of tree traversal examples on Stack Overflow

Comment: I have traversed the tree but facing problem in backtracking

Comment: Find the path between the root and the given node and just reverse it. You can do that with depth-first search, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as suggested, you can use a dfs algorithm.

```js
function dfs(o, target){
    if(o.id == target) return [target];
    if(!o.children) return false;
    let path;
    o.children.find(x=>path=dfs(x, target));
    if(path){
        return [o.id].concat(path);
    }
};
let sampleData={"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":8}]},{"id":6}]},{"id":3,"children":[{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":4}]}
let path;
[sampleData].find(x=>path=dfs(x, 9))
console.log(path);
```